# Child to child object prepopulation

Tags: related-list

Requirement :

Currently we have two Child object Related Lists under Account.

Service Request and Task.

When user clicks New in Service Request , Task record needs to be populated to Service Request record.

What are the possible approaches to do this ?

Comment: Are you looking to auto create Task record when Service Request record is created ?

Comment: @Devendra - It's the other way round . Task will be created first . Service Request needs to be auto populated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to prepopulate the field with the Task using the standard page layout.You need to create a VF page for this (VF page to create Service Request with Task prepopulated in Service Request)

In case you dont want to create Vf page, you can write a trigger on Service Request for beforeInsert scenario, which will get the task record related to that Account on which you created the Service Request and populate the field on Service Request, with the task.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Will the second case be possible under all scenarios ? Or only under certain cases?

Comment: You write the trigger...it will work Everytime :)